# Sqlite3 table primary key gets replaced

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I am having SQLite database where I have one table called tblUser,where I am having variables say Id,name,image,gender.

In my app,I am giving functionality to add,delete update the User entry (Common functionality). Say I have 2 record by default on the page with 2 users and that both are deleted. Now the 3rd record inserted will be provided Primary key as 3.

Now if I edit that particular record then it is not updated with new data rather the primary key of the same gets replaced with 1 when I call following function :

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database);
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "select UserId,UserAge,UserName,UserGender,UserImage from [tblUser]";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,0);
                UserDetail *DataObj = [[UserDetail alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];

                DataObj.UserAge = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,1);
                DataObj.UserName =    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
                DataObj.UserGender =   [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];
                DataObj.UserImage =   [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)];
                DataObj.isDirty = NO;
                [appDelegate.DataArray addObject:DataObj];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}
```

Note that I am calling this function when I come back to the page where listing of the user is shown after clicking save button of the page where all details need to be filled. Any hint will be much helpful. Thank you.

Comment: SQLite doesn't change primary keys on you, so there's got to be a bug somewhere else. I'd suggest showing us the SQL for editing record.

Comment: Also, to CL's point, how are you determining the `UserId` for the inserted record? If you're relying on SQLite to do that for you, make sure you use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` and not just `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. You might want to show us your SQL for inserting a new record. You say it was inserted as 3 and when you edit, it became 1, but we're all suspecting that the problem may well be in the inserting, not the editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `UserId` is an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`:
SQLite will create new IDs as one larger than the previously largest value,
but if the table is empty, it will [(re)start at 1](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: But it allows me to create once all my records are deleted,only problem occurs when I edit the record..!! Also note that Primary key is an integer number starting with 1.

Comment: If your code uses `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, SQLite will _not_ restart at 1, even if the table was erased. It restarts if you recreate table. But not if you just delete rows and start inserting again.